# Сумма элементов списка рекурсивно

Tags: python

Напишите рекурсивную функцию `rec_linear_sum(some_list)`, которая вычисляет сумму элементов переданного в неё линейного списка вещественных чисел, то есть такого списка, в котором нет вложений.

Мой код:

```
def rec_linear_sum(some_list):
    def sumL(some_list, s, i):
        if i < 0:
            return s
        else:
            return sumL(some_list, s + some_list[i], i - 1)
    return sumL(some_list, 0, len(some_list) - 1)
```

Чекер пишет, что я не использую рекурсию, но я пытался решить как раз через нее.
Помогите с рекурсией.

Comment: Не-а, это не рекурсия.

Answer (score 8):

я бы попроще написал:

```
def sum_(items):
    assert hasattr(items, "__getitem__"), "parameter [items] must be iterable"
    assert len(items), "parameter [items] must be of a non-zero length"
    if len(items) < 2:
        return items[0]
    return items[0] + sum_(items[1:])
```

Comment: За первое решение - плюсанул, а вот однострочник - я бы не стал неокрепшим детским умам :-) даже показывать. А то примут, как образец для подражания. Кстати, для "полного счастья" - еще бы проверку на пустоту списка добавить бы.

Comment: @passant, хорошее замечание, спасибо! исправил)